# traefik - expose secondary internal port via new subdomain

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I've written a .NET API application that listens on two ports:

- 5000 for regular HTTP requests (HTTP1)
- 5001 for gRPC (HTTP2)

I'm deploying my images via `docker-compose` using labels:

```
labels:
  - "traefik.enable=true"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myApi.rule=Host(`api.example.com`)"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myApientrypoints=websecure"
  - "traefik.http.routers.myApitls.certresolver=myresolver"
```

Now, my question is - if my container EXPOSEs 5000 as well as 5001, how do I setup a new subdomain so that I can allow regular web traffic as well as `gRPC`?

So that:

```
HTTP1 https://api.example.com -> container:5000
HTTP2 https://api-grpc.example.com -> container:5001
```

If there is a better way of achieving the same, please let me know. I cannot have `gRPC` listen on the same port as web traffic due to the strict `HTTP2` requirement, and I'd rather not use `gRPC-web`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```yaml
labels:
  - traefik.http.routers.http-router.rule=Host(`api.example.com`)
  - traefik.http.routers.http-router.service=http-service
  - traefik.http.services.http-service.loadbalancer.server.port=5000
  - traefik.http.routers.grpc-router.rule=Host(`api-grpc.example.com`)
  - traefik.http.routers.grpc-router.service=grpc-service
  - traefik.http.services.grpc-service.loadbalancer.server.port=5001
  - traefik.http.services.grpc-service.loadbalancer.server.scheme=h2c
```

Reference: [Specifying more than one router and service per container](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/routing/providers/docker/)

Comment: Lovely and concise answer, thanks! Was just missing a 'traefik.http.services.grpc-service.loadbalancer.server.scheme=h2c' and now it works!

Comment: @TroelsLarsen great! I will add this to answer